# How to set initial height of a TextInput field that grows dynamically as the user input length grows (React Native)

Tags: css, react-native, responsive-design

[image: My goal for initial display of TextInput]

I'm having trouble working through a problem with a TextInput field in React Native. In this portion of my form, the user might enter in a very long input. As such, I want the TextInput box to grow dynamically in size and keep consistent padding. I have solved that problem, however, I'm wondering how to set an initial height of this box that will still allow for this multiline dynamic functionality to persist. Right now, when I try to add an initial height, It removes that dynamic padding and multiline functionality.

Here's what I mean

[image: The padding does not persist when I pass an initial height]

I have tried adding an initial height, and I have tried adding a minHeight.

When I use height of 69, it looks good until the user types past that height. Then, the initial padding of 8px between the border and the textInput disappears.

I've tried adding a minHeight, but that just seems to give it a massive initial value.

[image: Some code of my TextInput]

Comment: check out the onContentSizeChange prop for TextInput

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that, Focus on `height: Math.max(35, height)` & `onContentSizeChange`

```
const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
const onContentSizeChange = event =>
            setHeight(Math.max(35, event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height));
   
(
<TextInput
  value={feedback}
  editable
  multiline
  numberOfLines={10}
  placeholder={'Write here...'}
  onChangeText={onTextChanged}
  onContentSizeChange={onContentSizeChange}
  style={{...styles.textInput, height: Math.max(35, height)}}
/>
)
```